# Growing a dynamic hash table

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

I'm writing a program in C that uses a hash table as a dictionary. When the load factor reaches 75 %, a new table is created with double the old size and the old hash table is freed from memory.

The problem is that the user's main program has access to only a few functions:

- `create_dictionary()` – returns a pointer to the dictionary
- `close_dictionary(dictionary)`
- `add_word(dictionary, word)`

So the user creates a dictionary, adds lots of words, and eventually the dictionary needs to grow. The helper function is automatically called in the background. The problem now is that the user doesn't know that the old dictionary has been replaced, and that the pointer to the old dictionary is no longer correct.

What is the best way to solve this problem? Can I somehow grow the hash table in place? Right now I allocate the new space, rehash the old words into it, then delete the old hash table

Comment: What is `dictionary`? If it is a pointer to the backing array, your encapsulation is probably too weak. It should be a pointer to some `struct` that never changes even if you need to reallocate. Otherwise, the function will have to `return` the new pointer. (BTW, your interface would be more useful if it also had a function to look something up in the dictionary…)

Comment: You're not the first person to implement a hash table in C. Have a look at simple existing implementations (eg the one from [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/): [`hash.h`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/hash.h;hb=HEAD), [`hash.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/hash.c;hb=HEAD)). If you have a question specific to your implementation, we need to see *your* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to have your pointer point to a support structure instead.  Inside that structure you put the size of the hash table, the number of elements it contains, and a pointer to the table.  When you detect that your 75% has been exceeded, you allocate a bigger table,  hash the old values into the new table then free the old table and make the pointer in the structure point to the new table